# set left widget as focused one in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using [card_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper) widget in my project. It is a good library, but there is a problem: the focused widget always stays on centre but I want the focused item to be the one on the left. How can I accomplish this with this library?

In the below picture, focused item is on centre, but yellow item, in my case, should be on the left.

[image]

Comment: have u looked at the api? https://pub.dev/documentation/card_swiper/latest/#pagination

Comment: yeah. Pagination shows dot's indicator mainly

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which could be useful for others. The example is for 4 items on view but you can customise it to as many as you want:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.purpleDark,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Swiper(
              index: chosenIndex,
              layout: SwiperLayout.CUSTOM,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(
                startIndex: 0,
                stateCount: math.min(4, listSize),
              ).addScale(
                [3, 1, 1, 1], // there should be 4 widgets in view with the first 3 times larger
                Alignment.topRight,
              ).addTranslate( // place the 4 items as I want
                [
                  Offset(-35.toResizableWidth(), 0),
                  Offset(30.toResizableWidth(), 0.0),
                  Offset(118.toResizableWidth(), 0.0),
                  Offset(200.toResizableWidth(), 0.0),
                ],
              ),
              itemWidth: 51.toResizableWidth(),
              itemHeight: 51.toResizableHeight(),
              controller: controller,
              itemCount: listSize,
              onIndexChanged: (newIndex) => setState(() => chosenIndex = newIndex),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => controller.next(),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 51.toResizableWidth(),
                    height: 51.toResizableHeight(),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$index',
                        style: AppTextStyles.styleS16W600.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 10.toResizableHeight(),
              horizontal: 20.toResizableWidth(),
            ),
            child: Text(
              LocaleKeys.rewards_day.tr(args: <String>[chosenIndex.toString()]),
              style: AppTextStyles.styleS20W600
                  .copyWith(color: true ? AppColors.greenPositive : AppColors.redNegative),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20.toResizableWidth(),
            ),
            child: Text(
              longText,
              style: AppTextStyles.styleS16W400.copyWith(color: AppColors.white100),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container()),
        ],
      ),
    );
```